# How to add category on the checkout header on magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, xml, header

I was able to add my header on the checkout page and payment page by adding this code in `Magento_checkout/layput/checkout_index_index.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  layout="1column"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

My header appears without category. I tried to add my cateogories like this, but is not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="checkout" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
            <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
            <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container" />
            <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Does anyone know how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the header with the cateogry on the checkout page we should:
In `Magento_Checkout\layout\checkout_index_index.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />           
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/> 
        <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>     
    </body>
</page>
```

and then add this css line:

```
.checkout-index-index .nav-sections, .checkout-index-index .nav-toggle {
 display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your theme's xml file:

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<themename>/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

Write this code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
      <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />
      <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
      <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
      <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false" />
      <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
      <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>
</body>
</page>
```